# what to offer as my back up?

Tags: vacation

I am an hourly employee who started 8 months ago. I don't get any benefits because they ensure to not work me over 33 hours (although occasionally I do). I want to take a 10 day vacation and my boss that said 10 days is too much and  to offer him back up plan. What should I offer him?  I noticed he does not want me to burden the other worker that did the job before me.

Comment: what sort of job?

Comment: It's not your job to find a replacement. It's your bosses job.

Comment: It is bad form in most (UK) businesses for a manager to contest a holiday that is not greater than 2 business weeks with due notice given. Look at your contract and what you are entitled to in terms of volume and frequency and notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He might be telling you that he thinks it's your responsibility to find people who are willing to cover your responsibilities while you're gone. Or that he wants you to be available to work remotely if you have a job where that is possible. Or to schedule that vacation for another time. Or to take some of it as unpaid time. Or some combination of these. Or something else.

It's hard to guess which without knowing a lot more about your workplace.

Especially since you're new to the company and the department, I'd suggest going in and saying "hi, regarding vacation planning alternatives.... As you know I'm new around here and don't yet have a good idea of what alternatives would be considered reasonable. Could you give me a bit more guidance, this first time?"

Generally, when you aren't sure you understand what management is saying, and the confusion is at all reasonable, it's more productive to ask them for clarification than to try to guess. Or to ask others to guess.